# white border of combo box in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a problem in my page.I have some combo boxes in it.In other browsers it looks very good but in IE-7 it looks very bad. It is bordered white in it. How can I solve this problem. Any idea ?

Comment: you should provide a link or screenshot for that.

Comment: Sorry I can't provide any link.

Comment: How are you implementing your comboboxes? Are they select elements replaced with JS? Are they text inputs with dropdowns added using JS or what? (Or did you mean "a select element" in the first place? These are usually rendered as drop down menus (not comboboxes, which are a **combination** of drop down menus and text inputs, hence the name).

Comment: I am using simple select element in cakePHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS set:

```
border:none;
border-color:transparent;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using CSS to change the border color to transparent.

Comment: I have already done it. I have set its margin and padding to 0 and also tried to set cell's background color same as background color of combo box.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a css reset in your projects it helps avoiding such problems.
[css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)